Spark Hbase Phoenix(SHC) connector result wrong value for Date field
I am new to the SHC connector.
I am trying to decode values stores in Hbase via Phoenix SQL using Spark.
Below is my Phoenix table syntax:
CREATE TABLE SOME_NAMESPACE.some_sample_table(
col1 VARCHAR NOT NULL,
col2 TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
col3 DOUBLE ,
col4 INTEGER ,
col5 DATE NOT NULL,
col6 VARCHAR,
CONSTRAINT col1_col2_col3_pk PRIMARY KEY (col1, col2, col5));

Insert statements:
upsert into SOME_NAMESPACE.some_sample_table values('col1_values4',
'2000-07-10 14:10:20',
348.78,
4001,
'2014-12-23',
'col4_values');

upsert into SOME_NAMESPACE.some_sample_table values('col1_values2',
'2015-07-10 14:10:20',
18.78,
201,
'2002-12-23',
'col6_values');

upsert into SOME_NAMESPACE.some_sample_table values('col1_values3',
'2016-07-10 14:10:20',
18.78,
201,
'2001-12-23',
'col6_values');

When I am trying to read the above table from Spark connector. I am getting proper values for Col1(Varchar) and Col2(Timestamp). However for col5(Date) column the values are not inline with the correct date timestamp as highlighted below.
Here is my catalogue and spark command:
def catalog = s"""{
     |"table":{"namespace":"SOME_NAMESPACE","name":"SOME_SAMPLE_TABLE","tableCoder":"Phoenix"},
     |"rowkey":"key1:key2:col5",
     |"columns":{
     |"c1":{"cf":"rowkey", "col":"key1", "type":"string"},
     |"c2":{"cf":"rowkey", "col":"key2", "type":"long"},
     |"c3":{"cf":"rowkey", "col":"col5", "type":"long"}
     |}
|}""".stripMargin


def withCatalog(cat: String): DataFrame = {
         spark.sqlContext
         .read
         .options(Map(HBaseTableCatalog.tableCatalog->cat))
         .format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase")
         .load()
}

val hbaseDf=withCatalog(catalog)
hbaseDf.show(truncate=false)

Output:
Actual Output
Column C3/Col5(date column) values are out of range. I think the decoder is not working properly for Date columns defined in Phoenix. For Timestamp column getting correct results.
Any help here will be highly appreciated.
Expectation is to receive following result:
c5
2365891200000
1040601600000
1009065600
